# multiply SELECT results with values from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have 3 tables with student data from different schools. I am supposed to get the count of students per school in one table(done) and then using the given probabilities to figure out how many students per set of probabilities. I have the results of students per school from another query.

Ex: I used a query to find the total number of students at school "CAA".
 If it is 198, then the probability distribution will be
(0.05*198, 0.08*198, 0.18*198, 0.3*198, 0.11*198, 0.28*198).
How do I grab those values from said table and multiply with my results?

I hope this makes sense and forgive me I am new to Postgres. I have attached my query to get the count and photos of the two relevant tables.

simulated_records:

```
record_id(PK bigint)   Status(text)    grade(text
 1                     CL              -
 2                     CEC             -
 3                     CEC             -
 4                     CEC             -
 5                     CAA             -
 6                     CAS             -
 7                     CAA             -
 8                     CAA             -
 9                     CAA             -
 10                    CL              -
```

school_probs:

```
school_code(PK bigint)  school(text)    probs(numeric)
1                       CAA             {0.05,0.08,0.18,0.3,0.11,0.28}
2                       CAS             {0.06,0.1,0.295,0.36,0.12,0.065}
3                       CBA             {0.05,0.11,0.35,0.32,0.12,0.05}
4                       CL              {0.07,0.09,0.24,0.4,0.06,0.09}
```

grade_values:

```
id(PK integer)   score(text)    grade(text
1                95-100         A
2                90-94          A-
3                80-89          B+
4                70-79          B
5                60-69          C
6                0-59           D
```

MY QUERY:

```
SELECT simulated_records.school, COUNT(simulated_records.school) as CountSchool
FROM simulated_records, school_probs
WHERE simulated_records.school = school_probs.school
GROUP BY simulated_records.school;
```

What I should be able to do is populate grades in the simulated records table based on the amount of students per school and using the probabilities(which breaks down how many kids should have what grade using a function.

Also the actual simulated records table has over 2000 records.

Expected results: The empty grade column in simulated_records would be filled with grades based on the count of students and the probability from school_probs.

```
record_id(PK bigint)   Status(text)    grade(text
 1                     CL              A
 2                     CEC             B
 3                     CEC             B
 4                     CEC             A
 5                     CAA             C
 6                     CAS             B
 7                     CAA             D
 8                     CAA             A
 9                     CAA             A
 10                    CL              C
```

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That has been [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for over two years now. You should really plan an upgrade to a current version (e.g. 10 or 11)

Comment: Please do not input images as examples or sample data since it is really hard to copy the data for test queries we should write. Furthermore I am seeing two times the same image. Please fix it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree but that is what they want us to use.

Comment: @S-Man sorry I went ahead and fixed it

Comment: @CCat please add your expected result. And where is your student count (table 1)?

Comment: @S-Man I added that in as well and added the missing table. Thanks!

Comment: Sry, I already miss the student count per school. Is there another table or how can these data be achieved from your 3 tables above. Additionally I do not understand what the table "simulated_records" should be?

Comment: Where is the 198 for CAA? What do you expect as output? Do you want 6 rows for each school? For CAA you want the rows: {A, 9.9 students (= 0,05 * 198)}, {A, 15.84}, ... , {D, 55.44}?

Comment: @S-Man there is no other table. Basically I need  towrite a
function using procedural language PL/pgSQL to randomly assign a grade to each record (for a student)in the table “simulated_records” based on the grade probability distribution for each school. So I first need to get the number of students per school using simulated_records where status is a student from said school. For example find the total number of students at school "CAA"
If it is 198, then the probability distribution will be(0.05*198, 0.08*198, 0.18*198, 0.3*198, 0.11*198, 0.28*198)

Comment: Then we will have 9.9 students to get A, 15.84 students to get A-, 35.64 students to get B+, 59.4 students to get B, 21.78 students to get C, and 55.44 students to get D. Obviously I would need to round up.

198 was the result from the full simulated records table that is too long.

The result at the end of everything should populate a grade where there is a dash in the simulated records.

Comment: For your example please add the data for students of the other schools. Please explain your order? Why is CL,A the first record, why is CL,C the tenth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=65a98d92016481b0a2e827e9c472a278)

```
SELECT 
    school,
    json_object_agg(gv.grade, s.students)                           -- 4
FROM (
    SELECT 
        s.school, 
        ceil(unnest(sp.probs) * s.students_per_school) students,    -- 2   
        generate_series(1,6) gs                                     -- 3
    FROM (
        SELECT 'CAA'::text as school, 198 as students_per_school    -- 1
    ) s
    JOIN school_probs sp ON s.school = sp.school                      
) s
JOIN grade_values gv ON gv.id = s.gs
GROUP BY school
```

Result:

```
school   json_object_agg
CAA      { "A" : 10, "A-" : 16, "B+" : 36, "B" : 60, "C" : 22, "D" : 56 }
```

Hoping this is the result you expect:

1. Getting your data from somewhere (simulate your table or subquery or whatever)
2. 1. `unnest` expands your `numeric` `probs` array into one row each element. This is the main trick
   2. multiply with your students
   3. `ceil` rounds up (otherwise you could do a `floor` for round down or `round` for normal rounding)
3. `generate_series` adds an `integer` column for the ability to join the `grade_values` table
4. Now you have one row for each grade per school (*see Edit below*). If this is your expected result, that's it. If you want to aggregate the grade values into one row per school you could do this `json_object_agg`

---

Edit: Version without aggregating:

```
SELECT 
    school,
    gv.grade, 
    s.students
FROM (
    SELECT 
        s.school, 
        ceil(unnest(sp.probs) * s.students_per_school) students, 
        generate_series(1,6) gs
    FROM (
        SELECT 'CAA'::text as school, 198 as students_per_school
    ) s
    JOIN school_probs sp ON s.school = sp.school
) s
JOIN grade_values gv ON gv.id = s.gs
```

Result:

```
school   grade   students
CAA      A       10
CAA      A-      16
CAA      B+      36
CAA      B       60
CAA      C       22
CAA      D       56
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out. Should help me figure out the rest of my problem

Comment: FROM (
        SELECT 'CAA'::text as school, 198 as students_per_school
    ) s
What if I wanted to not use CAA and 198 what if I got the school code and student count from another query?

Comment: Please add a simple use case and expected output

Comment: For ex: the actual simulated_records table has 100 records. Every time you see CAA or CL  that is a student from CAA or CL there are 9 schools. I can use a query to get the count per school code. Using the school_probs table I can get the probability of how many kids can get a A, B, C , etc. I need to assign a grade based on the count and probability. Here is my DB fiddle link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=74d45abd8eb464179729e3bd15a225ec

Comment: It would be really great if you could append some. tables to your question to show your expected result.

Comment: I just did. It is a bit difficult considering the real table has 100+ records.

Comment: It is alway necessary to evaluate the core problem with few very representative rows (one usual case, and some tricky exceptional cases). If we should solve your problem, we a) cannot analyse your whole record and. b) cannot type manually the data sets and c) have to know how the result should look like exactly. So it is necessary to make it as simple as possible for getting good results ;)

Comment: If I understand you the right way: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b4356d7eecb0db427f2845c9080f97d1 The part where I am calling the 'CAA' is only a placeholder for the whole table. I added some rows. But I am quiet unsure about your ordering

Comment: Thank you for responding. I was able to do what I wanted and complete the rest of the code I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect as a result, but here goes:

```
select school, factor, CountSchool
from (
      SELECT simulated_records.school, COUNT(simulated_records.school) as CountSchool
      FROM simulated_records, school_probs
      WHERE simulated_records.school = school_probs.school
      GROUP BY simulated_records.school
     ) eq
cross join (
    values 
         (0.05), (0.08), (0.18), (0.3), (0.11), (0.28)
    ) t (factor)
```

this would produce a result like this:

```
    school  factor  count_of
1   CAA 0.0500  198
2   CAA 0.0800  198
3   CAA 0.1800  198
4   CAA 0.3000  198
5   CAA 0.1100  198
6   CAA 0.2800  198
```

nb: You have not indicated how you will store the "factor" information.

Comment: My issue would be that there should be no hard coded values. Should be able to pull values from the table.

Comment: Not sure how I will store it. I am breaking down my problem bit by bit.